# jQuery UI Datepicker causing problems if Current Date is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Datepicker is working okay except that when I select the 'current date' it causes the other JS at the bottom of my script to fail. Here is the datepicker configuration I have

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    altField: "#alternate",
    altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/calendar2.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Select date",

    onSelect: function() {
      // Get the form and submit it on date click
      var form = document.getElementById('datepickerform');
      form.submit();
    }
  });
})
```

At the bottom of my script there is much more JS - which all works just fine if I don't select the 'current date' using the datepicker widget above. So to test the problem simplistically I removed all of the 'other' JS script and replaced it all with a simple JS alert notification. And sure enough the alert works okay with any dates - except (again) when I select the 'current date' on datepicker the JS alert doesn't trigger. Any ideas much appreciated

Comment: You're submitting the form when the user selects anything from the datepicker. That reloads the page, so nothing else should run.

Comment: All other dates  selected and submitted (except the current date) work just fine. It is literally only a problem when the current date is selected. The problem is that the 'current date' selection causes the other js at the bottom of script to fail.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Please post a [mre].

Comment: None at all. I removed 'on select-submit from the datepicker config. And the other JS (which is now just a simple alert) fails on any date selected.

Comment: I will take your suggestion and move the problem onto a new script and attempt to reproduce it with just the datepicker config above and a simple alert notification and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Barmar. The problem lay with todays date format on the referrer URL which is now resolved. Problem solved.